# Is DateTime.Now affected by changing the system clock?

Tags: c#, datetime

If I use DateTime.Now as part of software licensing authentication to enforce the number of days software can be used, can this be circumvented by simply changing the system clock?

If so is there a better way to get real UTC time?

Comment: Where would `DateTime.Now` get its value if not from the system clock?

Comment: do you have internet connection at users ?

Comment: @KirkWoll - the bios? By system clock I mean the calendar which the user can change in bottom right of the task bar

Comment: What clock (aside from the bios) would that widget be manipulating?

Comment: If I were a computer manufacturer I'd probably have an unchangable system time that runs off a quartz clock as well as a manipulatable time that the end-user can change. Hence the question ;)

Comment: "... a better way to get accurate system time": system time is *defined by the system clock*, so changing the system clock changes the system time.  You want a better way to get accurate *real* time.

Comment: We have a customer whose accounting system is so old that they have to change the system time to persuade it to post invoices to the correct month, but it disrupts other systems such as Kerberos if they forget to correct the time afterwards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If I use DateTime.Now as part of software licensing authentication to
>   enforce the number of days software can be used, can this be
>   circumvented by simply changing the system clock?

DateTime.Now uses the system clock, so yes it could be circumvented.

> If so is there a better way to get accurate system time?

Yes, you could query a time server over the www. But you know, even this could be circumvented because the user can modify his hosts file and replace the address you are using with his own proxy and return whatever time he likes. So it will all depend on how far do you want to get into protecting your software. If you really care about the intellectual property of your software you are better of purchasing a commercial licensing software.

Comment: But WWW response could be hijacked so wrong response could be returned

Comment: @sll You could sign the time with the services private key so that it couldn't be faked.

Comment: @Servy: private key could be extracted from your program's executable/dll and reused as well

Comment: @sll No, your program would only need your public key.

Comment: @sll No.  The client only has the public key of the service.  The service keeps the private key...private.  Obviously it would need to be a time service that you owned (which could obviously fetch its data from a more general time server).  This is of course all done for you if the service is an HTTPS service, not an unsecured service.  (It also needs to not have a self-signed cert).

Comment: And how does commercial licensing software that does not query a time server handle this?

Answer (score 6):

Everytime i have used this method for testing it has affected this, so the answer is yes it does affect it

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, the DateTime.Now obtains its value from the system clock.
A better way is to use a NTP server on Internet.

In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C) on codeproject you could find code that allows a client to connect to a NTP server